# What is `static inject...`

Tags: aurelia

I found this line of code in [Aurelia Dialog](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog/blob/master/src/examples/common-dialogs.js)

```
static inject = [DialogService];
```

This is the full class:

```
import {Prompt} from './prompt'; 
import {DialogService} from '../dialog-service'; 

export class CommonDialogs { 

   static inject = [DialogService]; 

   constructor(dialogService){ 
   this.dialogService = dialogService; 
   }  


     prompt(question){ 
     return this.dialogService.open({viewModel:Prompt, model:question}); 
     }; 
}
```

What is the `static inject` doing?  I get that it is injecting the dialog service into the constructor.  But why do it this way instead of the usual inject?

Comment: I found this from Rob which explains a bit: http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/aurelia-update-with-decorators-ie9-and-more/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the blog post you linked to mentions, `static inject` was the original way to do dependency injection. Once Babel started supporting decorators, we implemented the `inject` decorator to make Aurelia code look a little nicer. Under the covers, it simply adds the `inject` property to the class at runtime (https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/blob/master/src/decorators.js#L13).